# gray screen problem with disappearing menu in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, vnc

I tested several methods to resolve gray screen problem in Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL)
but I cannot resolve this problem until now
of course, I don't have any problem in Ubuntu 16.04 (WSL)
my configure in Ubuntu 16.04 is:

> nano /root/.vnc/xstartup

```
exec xfce4-session &
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
autocutsel -fork
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

And I don't have any problem with this configuration in Ubuntu 16
But in Ubuntu 18.04 I tested several methods like:

```
exec xfce4-session &
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
autocutsel -fork
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
#/etc/X11/Xsession
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinint/xinitrc
x-window-manager &
```

OR add

```
metacity &
nautilus &
```

OR use this method:

```
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
# fix to make xfce work:
startxfce4 &
```

but I cannot get result in Ubuntu 18.04

How can I do exactly to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error message solved when I uncomment my tag
see below code:

```
exec xfce4-session &
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
autocutsel -fork
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinint/xinitrc
x-window-manager &
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the gray screen is to change the xstartup file to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
env -i /bin/sh -c "export PATH=$PATH;
              export XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY;
              export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY;
              export HOME=$HOME;
              export LOGNAME=$LOGNAME;
              export USER=$USER;  
              /usr/bin/xfce4-session"
```

But the terminal icon in the vncviewer does not work. Have to find and execute the xfce4-terminal.